# C++ partial mutex/critical section lock

Tags: c++, events, mutex, critical-section

I am working in C++ in VS2010, and I have a container class with a bunch properties (getters and setters) (actually a bunch of objects with properties – but lets simplify it and assume that it is just a properties directly on the container class.

On this container class there is an Update function, and its important that the setters methods are blocked while the Update method is executing.

The app is multithreaded, so I was thinking to use mutex/events/critical section to handle this.

My question is: how can I lock/block the setters while the Update method is in action, without letting the setter methods block each other? Further, I will also need the setters to block the Update method.

In other words, I need a normal Critical Section mechanism, with the exception that the setters should not block each other.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: Are you also looking to protect concurrent setters from hitting identical properties (and if not, why not)?

Comment: All the properties are complete separate, and its therefore safe to alter them concurrently. A normal critical section could solve my problem; however I fear that it would give me a significant overhead, if the setters can block each other. The setters are called very frequently, and the Update method is called with minimum time space in between (meaning not that often).

Comment: my question wasn't whether setPropertyX is independent of setPropertyY. it is whether you need to guard against concurrent setPropertyX calls. if this is not a concern, see my answer below. (and honestly I'm befuddled how it can *not* be a concern, but you know the code better than I).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no requirement for the setters (ex: setPropertyX(value)) to be concurrently protected, this is doable with a single semaphore and a manually resettable event, where the initial resource count is the number of properties you're guarding against.

in any given setter:

- Wait on NoUpdatePendingEvent as set.
- Acquire semaphore resource (1)
- Update property value
- Release semaphore resource (1)

in the main update routine

- NoUpdatePending event clear
- Acquire semaphore resources (n)
- Do update
- Release semaphore resources (n)
- NoUpdatePending event set

where (n) is the number of properties you have. The initial state of NoUpdatePending is set, and waiting on it will NOT reset it (thus the manual-reset-only requirement). You cannot enter the update so long as any property is being updated. as soon as you enter the Update code and clear the NoUpdatePending event, incoming prop-updates will stall on the event and not consume semaphore resources. All running prop-sets will eventually release the resources needed for the update to continue.

All of that said, still consider property concurrency individually.

Comment: Thanks - sorry for misunderstanding your question - no, i don't need to guard against concurrent setPropertyX calls -so your suggestion will solve my problem - thanks

Comment: There is a threat of starvation, Update method want be called if setters called very frequently.

Comment: @Martin you mean a single crit-sec or (n) crit-secs, one for each property? The former will definitely work, but property sets will become synchronous. the latter will work, requiring a chain of crit-sec waits (one for each property). Pretty much a horde of ways to do this.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that the Update method doesn't access the setters, otherwise they'll block.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a critical section for each property. In the setter you acquire the property-specific critical section and do your work, this way each property won't block each other.

In the `Update` method acquire all the property-specific critical sections before doing the update. This will cause the setters to now block if anyone calls them whilst you're updating.

Comment: Thanks - yes that would solve the problem - ii would require quite a lot if critical sections :) - but still, a solution i will consider - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that uses only a critical section and an integer, and does not care how many setters you have:

in each setter:

- acquire critical section csUpdate
- InterlockedIncrement(&countSettersActive)
- release critical section csUpdate
- update property
- InterlockedDecrement(&countSettersActive)

in the main update routine:

- acquire critical section csUpdate
- while (InterlockedCompareExchange(&countSettersActive, 0, 0) != 0) { sleep(1); }
- do update
- release critical section csUpdate